# Mounting VHD, but not to a drive letter

Tags: hard-drive, security, c#, vhd, virtual-disk

Can I mount VHD so I can access it from my app, but not as a drive letter.
I need to access some files from my app (C# apps), but don't want it to be visible in Windows Explorer.

Answer (score -1):

what we did was make the program mount it and we made sure to have a certain name for the disk and after mounting the disk the program finds the disk with that name and removes the letter.

Comment: How is it solving OP's problem ?